# Airfoil meshing using ANSYS

Tags: fluid-mechanics, aerospace-engineering, ansys, cfd, meshing

Logged in a little time ago i have a new question. So I am trying to mesh an arifoil geometry using ANSYS meshing. Airfoil number is NACA 84-M profile. Running  2-D simulation my main objective is to find a good enough mesh for a specific task, which has to do mainly with active flow control, using a tiny jet nozzle located at the top back of my airfoil section. [image]
The outline of my airfoil sectin has been devided into 4 main sections. 
Lower part 
Upper front part
Jet nozzle part (only made of 2 points)
Upper back part (from jet nozzle through trailing edge of the airfoil)

Regarding my outter part of my flow domain i have used a C-type structured mesh seen below.
[image]

I left the nozzle spot and my main concern is the fact that i want to use a different face meshing for that specific spot. Trying to alter the number of cells due to the fact that the number should be enough to simulate flow phenomena. 
    Shall I use different meshes for the bottom and both of the upper two sections of my geometry? (remeber that the hole airfoil has been bi-sected into 4 different categories, described previously).
    Total chord length has been dimensionalized. Points arranged in the range of [0 to 1]. So the total chord length is 1m, or 1mm, it doesnt play a role. 
If you have many articles in consideration, please reply, anything should be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any code or any working example to work on?